# No change of brightness

Tags: brightness

My Dell laptop brightness is at stuck at maximum even if i decrease it to minimum value it doe snot change .

I don't understand what is the problem, any idea guys its AMD E1 processor.

I have Windows 8 currently and also the battery does not last for more than a short time , perhaps due to the screen brightness thing.

Comment: What's the exact model?

Comment: Its DELL Inspiron 15 3000 series AMD E1

Comment: @JourneymanGeek am i missing any other information?

Comment: You could always try and reinstall your display drivers and see if that fixes it.